# How can I create a "rain drops on camera lense" effect with the HDRP?

Tags: unity

I did follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG7zyogrUTs&t=115s but I did not made it cause I am using HDRP and they are not using HDRP so the problem is I can't use the normal materials being in HDRP mode help me if there is any way to do so or if there is another good video please.

[image]

In picture 1 I want these white particles on camera lens looks like the second picture I want water texture on these white particles.

[image]

Comment: How did you try to adapt your work to HDRP so far? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I edit the question please check if you can help. I want those round white particles looks like water as shown in the last picture.