# What is the difference between HDRP materials and normal materials

Tags: unity

[image][image]
I want to understand these materials I am always confused of using HDRP materials that which one is used for low texture which one is for high texture, for glass, for particles and many other.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "low texture" and "high texture"? What are you currently doing in your game that's giving you trouble in selecting/creating the right material for your needs?

Comment: I want to apply water texture on rain particles using HDRP VFX graph

Comment: How have you tried doing that so far? How do the results differ from what you want?

Comment: I want to apply water texture on that circle white rain drop particles using HDRP VFX graph.

Comment: U can see the difference between picture 1 camera lens and picture 2 camera lens I want my white circle particle like picture 2

Comment: This is starting to look and sound rather a lot like a duplicate of [your previous question asking about how to achieve a raindrop look using HDRP](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/173610/39518). Can you please clarify what is different about this question?

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate since with your edit yesterday it seems to be about solving the same problem as your previous question. If that's inaccurate, please edit your question to clarify the differences and we can re-open it.

Comment: Thanks for wasting some ones time I made it.

Comment: U can check it above.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, I recommend posting your solution as an answer to your original question.

Comment: Yes Sir i will it's actuly complex but i will try to make it simple for people.